# Change text colour based on a instance variable value in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to change the colour of a paragraph tag based on the value of an instance variable within my html.erb file. Problem I am having is that the colour of the text does not change and I am completely at a loss as to why this is the case, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**show.html.erb**

```erb
<% if @book.ONLINE == 'YES' %>
  <li><p style="color: green;">Book Online : <%= @book.ONLINE %></p></li>
<% else %>
   <li><p>Book Online : <%= @book.ONLINE %></p></li>
<% end %>
```

**html output**

```html
<ul class="container details">
   <!-- Book Status -->
   <li><p>Book Online : YES</p></li>
</ul>
```

Note : When I take the `if` statement out the text changes to green

When I check the console I get

```
@book.ONLINE #=> "YES"
```

Comment: What's your generated HTML? Maybe it's as simple as removing spaces around `=` in `style = "color: green;"`? BTW `ONLINE` for a column name goes against convention and I would personally not do this.

Comment: Il add the generated html now, and yeah I plan to refractor my columns once I go to production. For the style I tested it without the if statement and the field changes to Green

Comment: What does `@book.ONLINE` return? Can you check it in the console?

Comment: So when I check the console I get :                                                                           >>  @book.ONLINE
=> "YES"

Comment: I suggest to not use inline style but a CSS class instead.

Comment: If I were to use a CSS class instead how would I fit it into the code I have?

Comment: Looks like condition does not trigger, what is value of `@book.ONLINE.inspect` and `@book.ONLINE.class.name`?

Comment: My advise: stick to conventions, i.e. (a) don't use all-caps method names and (b) don't use strings as a replacement for booleans. Make that `online?` and have it return `true` or `false` – it will make your debugging life much easier. Plus, `<% if @book.online? %>` is much more succinct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys i took everything on board I ran a migration to change the field name as suggested by Marek and Stefan and the code works as expected now (Not really sure why this is the case). Thanks Stefan for pointing that out, that is a much cleaner way of doing it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<% if @book.online =='YES' %>
<li><p style="color: green;">Book Online : <%= @book.online %></p></li>
<% else %>
<li><p style="color: red;">Book Online : <%= @book.online %></p></li>
<% end %>
```